# dynamic proxy soap web service client in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Is there any way to use soap-rpc web services such that the client is generated via a shared interface? Restful web services do it this way, but what about soap based? Do you always have to use a tool like Axis or CXF to generate your stubs and proxies, or is there something out there that will set it up dynamically?

Thanks.

**EDIT #1:**

To clarify, I'm looking to do something like this:

Common interface:

```
@WebService
public interface MyWebService {

   @WebMethod
   String helloWorld();
}
```

This common interface can already be used to create the server side component. My question is: **can this type of common interface be used on the client side to generate dynamic proxies?** Restful web services do it this way (Restlets & CXF) and it seems the .Net world has this type of functionality too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would see [this tutorial of JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html) useful for your purposes:

In the example code the Web Services Client is configured by adding an annotation `@WebServiceRef` with a property pointing to the WSDL location to the client implementation class and no tools are needed to access the stuff from the Web Service that is referenced.

Was this the way you would like to have it, or did this even answer to right question?

Comment: I think you want this link: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html it is up to date.

Comment: I was hoping that it could be dynamically generated, rather than on build - but this works too. Thanks.

Comment: I'll wait the time limit out to make sure nothing else comes along, if not I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but if you don't want to rely on JAX-WS/JAXB-generated artifacts (service interfaces and binding objects), you can make use of the [`Service`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html) and [`Dispatch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.html) APIs. For example:

```
QName serviceName = new QName(...);
Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
QName portName = new QName(...);
String endpointAddress = "...";
service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointAddress);
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
SOAPMessage request = ...;
SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(request);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no - this is not quite what I'm looking for. See my edit above.

Answer (score 2):

Check Apache CXF. [Configuring a Spring Client (Option 1)](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call a webservice, you must have knowledge of methods implemented on it. For that, We need to make stubs OR we can read it from WSDL.

I have created a WS client, using AXIS2 libraries, which is without stubs. The thing is, for each diff. WS we need to create response handles.

You can call any WS method using SOAP envelops and handle the response.

```
//common interface for response handlers...
//implement this for diff. web service/methods

public interface WSRespHandler{
    public Object getMeResp(Object respData);
}

//pass particular handler to client when you call some WS
public class WebServiceClient {
    public Object getResp(WSRespHandler respHandler) {
        ...
        return repHandler.getMeResp(xmlData);
    }
}
```

Please check the link below, which shows the example interface for WS client.

http://javalibs.blogspot.com/2010/05/axis2-web-service-client-without.html

For every diff. WS method we can have diff. implementation for `WSRespHandler` interface, which will help parsing the response.

Comment: This sounds **very** close to what I am asking for. Do you have a complete example?

Comment: See these URLs, it shows how to use Axis2 for creating SOAP based client for WS.

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/java-web-service-client-read-array-list

http://www.developer.com/java/web/article.php/3863416/Using-Axis2-and-Java-for-Asynchronous-Web-Service-Invocation-on-the-Client-Side.htm

This will allow you to use common WS client code to call any WS. You need to implement the `WSRespHandler` for specific response.

Thanks,
Paarth Barot.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing java so well, but being forced to learn some to accomplish a task that I was given, I needed to consume a .Net service that I have already written, I had to do a little research.

I found that 99% of the examples/samples/problems with invoking a method call against a .Net service, or any service for that matter involved using J2EE (ServiceManager) or build classes and a proxy that reflect the service being invoked.  Unfortunately for me, none of this would work.  I was working "in a box".  I could not add new classes, could not WSDL references, did not have J2EE, but DID have access to the standard java libs.
I am used to doing this sort of thing in pretty much every other language but java, but now there was no choice, and java it was.

A lot of digging and figuring out all new terminology, methods, classes, etc, I knew I was getting close, but was having issues with some small items to complete the task.
Then I came across this post: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-jaxmsoap/

As long as you have some sort of idea of what you need to send the soap service in term of the soap envelope, the above link will give you the information you need to be able to invoke a service without the classes, wsdl class generators and J2EE, apache or other dependencies.

In an hour from the time I read the mentioned article, I had a class working and about 10 minutes later, converted the code to the "in the box" solution.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tuscany might help you, although it may be heavier than you want
http://tuscany.apache.org/

Comment: I've seen Tuscany before, but I can't seem to find any docs indicating how to get started, what it does exactly, etc.

Comment: Starting it is fairly easy, there are some tutorials here http://tuscany.apache.org/java-sca-documentation-menu.html

Comment: regarding what it does, simply put, you define components (may be written in java, c++ and number of other languages) and dependency injection in a way very similar to Spring (you can actually use Spring contexts as components). The beauty is, that in Tuscany any component may sit anywhere in the world (other JVMs on other computers, client browsers, ...) and where they sit and how they connect to each other is configurable outside business logic. You may easily expose a component as a SOAP service and later reconfigure it to use RMI. So you don't write nor generate any proxies on your own.